# Возврат к определенному ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Созданы и соединены последовательно 4 viewController, как с 4 ViewController вернуться на второй ?

```
ViewController2 * detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Пробывал таким образом, программа вылетает с ошибкой.

Comment: pushViewController - это переход вперед по стеку, то есть это добавление контроллера в стек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать вот таким образом -

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];`

Comment: Огромное спасибо !

Comment: @ВикторМишустин всегда пожалуйста, обращайтесь